# Is it possible to get a section of a word in an array (C++11)

Tags: arrays, c++11

Let's say we a string array of full names that contains {"John Doe", "Bill Gates", "Tyler Maxwell Gordon"}

What if I wanted to get the first, middle and last names of these people?

So,

first names will be John, Bill, and Tyler

middle names will be blank, blank and Maxwell

last names will be Doe, Gates, and Gordon

Is this possible? I am a python user and very new to c++11! In python, I would figure out a way to slice. But, I noticed it is not as simple to slice in c++. So, I came to the masters for help!

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: `std::string` has [functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for finding specific characters in strings and obtaining substrings. Have you tried to use those?

Comment: The full name is space-separated?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I do understand the concept of substrings but with my program, the user can enter any name with any length. So, is there a way you can parse it every time there is a whitespace?

Comment: @yumetodo yes! The user will enter their full names and whatever they enter will be stored in an element of the array

Comment: If you understand substrings, then where's the difficulty? You just separate each string into substrings at space characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. One of the easier ways to split the string up into its parts is to use `std::getline` with a delimiter, in your case a space character.  Here is a quick example of what you're looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names = {"John Doe", "Bill Gates", "Tyler Maxwell Gordon"};

    for (const auto& elem : names)
    {
        // split parts of names delimited by space
        std::istringstream iss(elem);
        std::string token;
        std::vector<std::string> firstMiddleLast;
        while (std::getline(iss, token, ' '))
        {
            firstMiddleLast.push_back(token);
        }

        // do whatever you'd like with tokenized parts...
        if (firstMiddleLast.size() == 2)        // -- no middle name -- //
        {
            std::cout << "first: " << firstMiddleLast[0]
                << "\nlast: " << firstMiddleLast[1] << std::endl;
        }
        else if (firstMiddleLast.size() > 2)   // -- has middle name -- //
        {
            std::cout << "first: " << firstMiddleLast[0]
                << "\nmiddle: " << firstMiddleLast[1]
                << "\nlast: " << firstMiddleLast[2] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```